New "Jobs" feature cannot search correctly for "C#"
So I clicked through to the new 'Jobs feature', hoping it was bringing back the old jobs feature (it isn't).  But it's also not bringing us a functional job search, either.  If you search for C#, it throws away the hash sign.  The search is incredibly rudimentary, as well, even though you'd expect it would be just a drag/drop from Indeed's site.
Anyway, it's in beta, so I shouldn't criticize I guess.  When it's defective within 2 searches and 15 seconds, though, that feels more like an alpha.
I am curious if this will perhaps integrate with Stack Overflow in some manner (I feel like the old jobs feature might be useful here).  Or be technologist-specific?  Where are you guys going with this?

"Anyway, it's in beta, so I shouldn't criticize I guess" - isn't that exactly what a beta is for?

You've tagged this as a [bug], so I've edited your title to focus on the bug you're reporting.  That said, your last paragraph seems perhaps more suited to a discussion.

Criticize away. Brutally humiliate is where you cross a line :)

See Known Issues with MVP Stack Overflow Jobs Launch (and as to where they are going with this: Testing a new version of Stack Overflow Jobs

Good to see that after 3 months, they've yet to fix a bug related to one of the most used languages out there... #workingasintended

C# minus the # and you get C. That's a feature not a problem! (j/k) Come to think of it, I would very much like to not have hordes of C# programmers responding to my C programming job ad :)

Funny. With Jobs I would have expected Objective-C.

@RyanM Thanks for that.  Would you think I should remove the last paragraph?

C# still not working correctly, getting mostly C and C++ jobs.

Had the same question today. Still the same thing, searching C# gives me C and C++ results. No change yet. Annoying.
